# Issue with Helmet and Express 4.17

Tags: javascript, typescript, http-headers, same-origin-policy, helmet.js

for a university project we are currently completing a web-app (we are using Express).
As I'm interested in the security issue, I wanted to make sure that our app is safe with Helmet.
Unfortunately, despite referring to the documentation, it doesn't seem to work.
The headers are exactly the same, without any variation.

[image]

You can find the app.ts file in the issue here: [Issue Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/218)

Comment: Just want to acknowledge that I saw this and will respond [on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/218) you opened.